# Want to access notifications storage in android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I'm trying to get the notifications from the database.
I don't know wheather notifications are stored in database or not.
Looking for URI to be use in `query()`.
Please share if you have any idea and concept behind notifications.

Answer (score 0):

There is no query to get all notifications list or there is no database which will store notifications.

What you can do is, read notification and store it in your own database.

you can refer [this](https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/11/reading-notification-using-notificationlistenerservice.html) to read notification from status bar.

**Note : While Testing the application in a emulator or a physical device enable Notification access in Settings->Security in order to read notification messages.**

Comment: but we can access the notification history from Nitification Logs. HOw this works.